# JavaScript: If statement on Array declaration

Tags: javascript, jquery, conditional-operator

Is it possible to put an if statement within an Array Declaration?

Code:

```
dayOfWeek = [if($('#sunday').checked()){$('#sunday').val()}];
```

> Browser error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token if.

I tried too:

```
$('#domingo').checked() ! $('#domingo').val() : 0
```

> Browser error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token !

**EDIT**

As @bažmegakapa answered the code that **works with no error** is:

```
diasSemana = new Array($domi.is(':checked') ? $domi.val() : null, $lun.is(':checked') ? $lun.val() : null);
```

This did not work:

```
$('#domingo').checked() ? $('#domingo').val() : 0
```

Browser showed this error: Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'checked'

Regards!

Comment: Use `[]` instead of `new Array()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need is called the [ternary or conditional operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator):

```
$('#domingo').checked() ? $('#domingo').val() : 0
```

However, it is not a good idea to query the DOM twice for the same element. Save the resulting jQuery object into a variable beforehand and reuse it:

```
var $domi = $('#domingo');
dayOfWeek = [$domi.checked() ? $domi.val() : 0];
```

I don't know what `.checked()` is, maybe you meant `.is(':checked')`.

[Some fiddle demo to play with](http://jsfiddle.net/X5w8G/)

Comment: great answer! The first approach showed me an error but second worked fine. Regards

Comment: @eyyo Yep, the error is due to the `.checked()` function which does not exist :).

Answer (score 4):

Try using the javascript ternary operator, documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/be21c7hw%28v=vs.94%29.aspx):

```
$('#domingo').checked() ? $('#domingo').val() : 0
```

Comment: This code is showing me this error: Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'checked'. Thanks anyway